# How to prove that $n^4/2^n$ is a monotonic sequence for large $n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can you proof $a_n=\dfrac{n^4}{2^n}$ is monotonic (above a certain n)? When I do $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ I get: $$\frac{-n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1}{2^{n+1}}$$ but after that I have no idea what to do. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: It is not monotonic (unless you restrict $n$ to be above a certain threshold).

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry for confusion, I'll adjust question.

Comment: Observe that $-n^4+\ldots<0$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^4}{2^{n+1}}\div \frac{n^4}{2^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^4}{n^4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}<1$,

$a_{n+1}<a_{n}$ for n sufficiently large.

Comment: This makes sense. I can't seem to find a theorem in my book about that tho, so I guess I can't use this on exams.

Comment: Which book are you using?  I think your instructor would accept this type of argument, even if it isn't explicitly stated in your text.

Comment: It's written by the professor herself, not really a book but I don't know the english word for it, but you have a point, I might use it. Thanks.

Comment: For some types of sequences, such as this one, looking at the ratio of consecutive terms is simpler than considering the difference of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log$ is a strictly increasing transformation, you could look at $\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)$ which simplifies to
$$
4\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)-\log 2=4\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\log(2^{1/4})\right].
$$
The RHS expression above is negative whenever $n$ is large enough so that
$$
1+\frac{1}{n}<2^{1/4}\iff n>\frac{1}{2^{1/4}-1}\approx 5.2852135.
$$
So $a_6>a_7>\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $f(x)=x^4 2^{-x}$.

Since $f'(x)=x^3 2^{-x}(4-x\log 2)$, one has that $f$ is strictly decreasing for $x>4/\log 2\approx 5.77$.

In particular, $$a_{n+1}=f(n+1)<f(n)=a_n$$ for $n\geq 6$.